# Redirection to lightning app using apex or configuration change --- lightning only

Tags: lightning, single-sign-on

We have 2 different lightning app. we are sso enabled organization now planning to sso from another place. Is there any way to redirect the user to the different lightning app after sso validation

As we have multiple lightning apps and a user can access all of them. Say a user is working on Lightning App "APP1" and logged out after working for some time. Now when he logged back in by default he landed in "App1"

Now we don't want that. We have a different place to do single sign on to our Salesforce Org. We want if the SSO is originated from place 1 it will open "App1" if originated from place 2 it should open "App 2" ignoring which app user was during the last login. hope this helps.

Received official reply from salesforce support

"Lightning apps are not url addressable at this time."

Comment: Possible to put some more detail?

Comment: Just came to know from salesforce support this is not possible inlightning

Comment: It would be good if you can write your experience with support team in clear and simple language, so others can benefit from the same.

Comment: Hi Avijit, I am in the same situation now.. Did u get to resolve this ?

Comment: it is not possible till date